# Enable/disable bootstrap popover when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my Django project i have a very simple form containing just an input element and a submit button. Django form looks like this:

```
class CoopAnonymousEnterForm(forms.Form):

    nickname = forms.CharField(min_length=3, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                                        'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder': 'Enter nickname here',
                                                        'data-container': 'body',
                                                        'data-toggle': 'popover',
                                                        'data-placement': 'top',
                                                        'data-content': 'Enter at least three characters.',
                                                        }))
```

My page contains the following:

```
                <form role="form" action="/anonymous_enter/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nickname">-->
                        {{ anonymous_enter_form.nickname }}
                    </div>
                    <button id="anonymous-enter-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default green">Start anonymously</button>
                    <button id="test-popover" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        Click!
                    </button>
                </form>
...
<script>

    $("#test-popover").on('click', function(){
        var anonymous_nickname = $("#id_nickname").val();
        if (anonymous_nickname.length <= 2) {
            $('#id_nickname').popover();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I would like this popover to appear only when user entered less than three characters into an input and clicked "test-popover" button. But the problem is that popover appears only when i click that input once again - not when the button is clicked.

Could you show me the right way to do that please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script does the right way:

```
<script>

   $("#test-popover").on("click", function(){

        var anonymous_nickname = $("#id_nickname").val();
        if (anonymous_nickname.length <= 2) {
            $('#id_nickname').popover('show');
        } else {
            $('#id_nickname').popover('destroy');
        }
    });
</script>
```